# My code breaks WooCommerce Multilingual Currency Switcher

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

WPML Woocommerce Multilingual does not support currency setting depending on user location, so we made our own code:

```
function geoIPLocator() { 
global $woocommerce_wpml; 

$currency='EUR'; 
$geo=new WC_Geolocation(); 
$geo->init(); 
$country=$geo::geolocate_ip($geo::get_ip_address() ); 

if(isset($_SESSION['locator'])) { 
   if($_SESSION['locator']['IP']= =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] && strlen($_SESSION['locator']['IP' ])>0) { 
    $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->s et_client_currency($_SESSION['locator'][ 'currency']); 

    return; 
   } 
} 

if($country['country']=="RU" || $country['country']=="BY") { 
    $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->s et_client_currency('RUB'); 
    $currency='RUB'; 
} else { 
    $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->s et_client_currency('EUR'); 
    $currency='EUR'; 
} 

$_SESSION['locator']=array("IP" =>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "ISO"=>$country['country'], "currency"=>$currency); 
} 

add_action( 'init', 'geoIPLocator', 5);
```

The problem is that it breaks regular currency switcher. When this code is on, we can't switch currency to any other. Is it because we don't save or check if a user already has some currency set up to him (like the manual switcher does)?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think if a _user currency_ exist it has to be set in `usermeta` table, and if it's the case, you could use the function `get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);` with also `$user_ID = get_current_user_id();`. But when searching and reading about similar cases over internet, i always fall on WPML multi-currency switcher not solved issues. The support team of WPML tell always that this kind of features are not supported and they kindly redirect people to expert developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected code

```
function geoIPLocator() {
   try {
           global $woocommerce;

           if ( isset($woocommerce) && gettype($woocommerce) == 'object' && property_exists($woocommerce,'session') && gettype($woocommerce->session) == 'object' && property_exists($woocommerce->session,'get') ) {
                   $manual_switch=$woocommerce->session->get('client_currency', null);

                   if ( $manual_switch == null ) {

                           global $woocommerce_wpml;

                           $currency='EUR';
                           $geo=new WC_Geolocation();
                           $geo->init();
                           $country=$geo::geolocate_ip($geo::get_ip_address());


                           if(isset($_SESSION['locator'])) {
                                   if($_SESSION['locator']['IP']==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] && strlen($_SESSION['locator']['IP'])>0) {
                                           $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->set_client_currency($_SESSION['locator']['currency']);

                                           return;
                                   }
                           }

           if($country['country']=="RU" || $country['country']=="BY") {
                   $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->set_client_currency('RUB');
                   $currency='RUB';
           }  
           else {
                   $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency_support->set_client_currency('EUR');
                   $currency='EUR';
           }

                           $_SESSION['locator']=array("IP"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "ISO"=>$country['country'], "currency"=>$currency);
                   }
           }

   } catch (Exception $e) {
           $e->getMessage();
   }

}

add_action( 'init', 'geoIPLocator', 5);
```